# How to get top level node in ASP Tree View

Tags: asp.net, sorting, treeview, treenode

I have a sorting function which accepts TreeVIew Node as argument and then sorts the node. How do I pass top node to this function?

Here's the code of my Tree View:

```
<asp:TreeView id="mytv" runat="server"></asp:TreeView>
```

Here's my sorting function code:

```
private void(TreeNode node)
{
   rest of code here
}
```

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
sort(mytv.TopNode)
```

And

```
sort(mytv.Nodes)
```

Comment: How are sorting the Nodes?

Comment: What do you mean by "top node"? Do you mean the root node in TreeView?

Comment: Yes I mean root node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
TreeNode currentNode = treeView.SelectedNode;
while (currentNode.Parent != null)
{
    currentNode = currentNode.Parent;
}
```

You are iterating from some node (does not matter which one) and go up the hierarchy until the `Parent` of the current node is `null`, that is, the current node is the `Root`.

Also, here is the class reference for the TreeView:

[TreeView class reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You will be able to figure out, from the class reference that

```
sort(mytv.Nodes)
```

did not work because Nodes is not a node but rather a collection of nodes.

Also, the TreeView does not have a `TopNode` attribute.